# Python decoding of particular image

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to decode and display a particular image format for a planetary image encoded according the PDS standard. I am using Pillow and I need to implement a bit decoder but after various attempts I have no good results. Could anyone help me to implement this particular Pillow decoder? I would provide more information when needed

For sure, I will provide information of the encoding for the PDS file I want to use. These are the important lines from the header of the file :

```
POINTERS TO DATA OBJECTS                                        
BROWSE_IMAGE=                 = 20480 <BYTES>                                
IMAGE                         = 53248 <BYTES>   

OBJECT DESCRIPTION                                               

OBJECT                         = IMAGE                                        

FIRST_LINE                  = 1                                            
LINE_PREFIX_BYTES           = 0                                            
LINE_SUFFIX_BYTES           = 0                                            
LINES                       = 1024                                         
LINE_SAMPLES                = 1024                                         
SAMPLE_TYPE                 = MSB_UNSIGNED_INTEGER                         
SAMPLE_BITS                 = 16                                           
SAMPLE_BIT_MASK             = "2#0000001111111111#"                        
END_OBJECT                     = IMAGE
```

Is that clear enough? that is the part of the header defining the encoding method of the image. The whole file contains both the header and the image itself. I obviously need a pillow decoder, and precisely a bit decoder, but mine does not work.

And this will be my code for the bit decoder:

```
from PIL import  Image, ImageFile

class DarkImageFile( ImageFile.ImageFile ) :

 format = 'IMG'
 format_description = 'IMG dark frame'


 def _open( self ) :     

   self.size = (1024,1024)      
   self.mode = 'F'                  # data representation mode
   self.tile = [ ("bit", ( 0,0 ) + self.size, 53248, (10,6, 0, 3) ) ] 

Image.register_open( "IMG", DarkImageFile )   
Image.register_extension( "IMG", ".img" )
```

Comment: could you post your attemptiing codeds

Comment: Good edit, removed the downvote and comment. I don't have much experience in this, but now you do have more chance of someone being able to help you.

Comment: Have you checked out the [`planetaryimage` library](https://planetaryimage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html)? Here's a nice online [Jupyter tutorial](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/godber/dfb5d012fda603619ab9/raw/b1db599f53a5c468075ff854e9056698bd005cc7/gistfile1.json) reading PDS files using that library.